# Haskell-style linked list addition in Rust Vectors

Tags: haskell, rust

Consider a (dumb) function merging two sorted integer lists in Haskell:

```hs
merge :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
merge xs ys = reverse $ merge' xs ys []

merge' :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
merge' [] ys acc = (reverse ys) ++ acc
merge' xs [] acc = (reverse xs) ++ acc
merge' (x:xs) (y:ys) acc
    | x < y     = merge' xs (y:ys) (x:acc)
    | otherwise = merge' (x:xs) ys (y:acc)
```

How can we replicate this `(x:acc)` behavior in Rust, without traversing through the entire vector?

The documentation for [Linked Lists](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html) tells us *not* to use it but to use `Vec` instead.
If we use `Vec`, is there a way to make it

1. Purely functional
2. Not have any mutable parameters
3. Not rely on copying the entire vector and using `add` (ownership problems)?

Comment: Can you tell us about your justification on these three requirements? It does not seem to be possible...

Comment: Haskell uses finger trees instead of linked lists

Comment: @MichaelLitchard I assume you're talking about Data.Sequence, but I don't see how that's relevant here. The question is about how to replicate `[a]`'s behavior in Rust, not how to get better behavior in Haskell.

Comment: If your issue is efficiently prepending values, take a look at VecDeque.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something like [im](https://docs.rs/im/15.0.0/im/) which might satisfy all three of your requirements.

Comment: Also relevant: [`itertools::merge`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.1/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.merge)

Comment: Short answer: no. What aspects of Haskell's list do you care about? Depending on what you want, `std::iter::Iterator` might be enough. Linked lists are pretty rarely what you want in Rust (you'll often run into ownership problems).

Comment: Even *Haskell's* own `Vector`/`Array`s require mutability if you want to both avoid the inefficiencies of linked lists and avoid copying the structure on every operation. I don't see why you'd expect Rust to be able to do better.

Comment: Whilst maybe not appropriate for idiomatic Rust applications, as the docs suggest, I would have thought LinkedList *would* be the right tool if you're looking to use an immutable pattern.